# Questions on Phenomenology

Tags: phenomenology, heidegger, husserl

This is from https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/phenomenology/#DiscPhen

Section 4 paragraph 9

One of Heidegger’s most innovative ideas was his conception of the “ground” of being, looking to modes of being more fundamental than the things around us (from trees to hammers). Heidegger questioned the contemporary concern with technology, and his writing might suggest that our scientific theories are historical artifacts that we use in technological practice, rather than systems of ideal truth (as Husserl had held). Our deep understanding of being, in our own case, comes rather from phenomenology, Heidegger held.

What does he mean by technological practice?

What does he mean by ‘systems of ideal truth’?

Comment: Would it be that Heidegger sees scientific discoveries more as artifacts that enable new technological applications (Maxwell's laws -> radar, radio, ...) than as a search for the "truth" about how the world is, devoid of any practical intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, one should make a clear distinction between philosophical texts and encyclopedia entries. Heidegger did not write this entry so we can't really ask what he meant by such or such excerpt.

One might argue that it makes sense when referring to key concepts of an author; but it still drives us in a muddy landscape for at least two reasons. First, through the life of a philosopher, words and concepts have their own lives. That is their meaning will often evolve over time, sometime slowly toward some kind of specification, sometimes abruptly when the philosopher is taking a new path. A prime example in Heidegger work is the term *Dasein*. There is a clear rupture in its meaning between *Sein und Zeit* and *Die Beiträge*, and it altogether disappear in the latter writings. Second, outside of the context of a philosophical texts (but naturally still inside the philosophical thought of a given author), some terms and even key ones will have a wide range of meaning. This makes it very difficult for an answer to be neither extremely vague nor a whole university course on the subject. A prime example would be Platon's *eidos* and *idea*.

Now back to your question, trying to patch things up:

1. "Technological practice" is not a key term in Heidegger writing and it here it should be understood in its most mundane way. Technological practice is the the usage we make of technology in the contemporary occidental society when we build planes or when we make two particles collide. For more on this subject, a key text would be Heidegger's conference *Die frage nach der Technik* (*The Question Concerning Technology*).
2. As for "systems of ideal truth", it is also hardly a term used by Heidegger as such, but it points more clearly toward a key aspect of his philosophy. Namely, he criticizes the scientific view of truth. See *Vom Wesen der Wahrheit* (*On the essence of truth*, following translations will be from or inspired from that of John Sallis). Heidegger first conducts an inquiry on the usual accepted sense of truth, which is shared with the scientific one. He shows how, in the usual sense:

   > Das Wahre, sei es eine wahre Sache oder ein wahrer Satz, ist das, was stimmt, das Stimmende.

   > The true, be it of a true thing or a true sentence, is what is in agreement with/what is conform, the accordant.

   For example, by "true gold" we mean a piece of mineral that is conform to what gold is ; and when we say that "the sky is blue" is true sentence, we mean that its meaning is in agreement with the state of the sky. Truth is commonly understood as accordance ("Übereinstimmung").

   Heidegger then questions this view further. When I see a golden coin and say the true sentence "This is a golden coin", what is in accord with what? Hardly the sentence and the coin! Since one is made of gold and the other is immaterial. There must be a third something that can asses or measure this accordance. This can't be the individual as, phenomenologically, this accordance is a pre-given ("eine Vorgabe"); that is the golden coin comes in the open of my world as such. This third something is actually "the open" (*Das Offene*), which is the domain for this measure and as such what fundamentally measures it ; as it gives it its measure. So, conclude Heidegger:

   > Dann muß das, was die Richtigkeit erst ermöglicht, mit ursprünglicherem Recht als das Wesen der Wahr-heit gelten.

   > Then what first makes correctness possible must with more original right be taken as the essence of truth.

   And there goes the usual (and scientific) acceptation of what fundamentally truth is, and opens for Heidegger the real question toward the essence of truth:

   > Wahrheit ist nicht ursprünglich im Satz beheimatet. Zugleich aber erhebt sich die Frage nach dem Grunde der inneren Möglichkeit des offenständigen und ein Richtmaß vorgebenden Verhaltens

   > Truth does not originally reside in the proposition. But at the same time the question arises of the ground of the inner possibility of the open comportment which pregives a measure.

Comment: Hi, thank for the response Johan, I think there seems to be an inconsistency that I have spotted within it: you say that the gold coin and the proposition doesn’t have an accordance but then say that something can assess this accordance.

Comment: You're right! And in a way, this is the heart of the problem. Don't forget that Heidegger wants to show that this idea of the truth has not be questioned deep enough: at the same time, the golden coin and the sentence "the coin is made out of gold" are two totally different things and yet, you would agree that the sentence is true, in the usual sense of being in accordance. Whence the leading question of Heidegger: where does the accordance stems from? What is this thing more fundamental in the question of the truth?

Comment: Pardon me for my ignorance Johan, but I still don’t see how what he is saying refutes the scientific conception of truth. Also you haven’t told me where the accordance comes from in the answer you merely stated that there exists a measure for it.

Comment: 1) He does not exactly refute this conception of truth, but rather he shows how what we took for a robust and straight-forward definition has it flaws and is imperceptibly grounded on something more fundamental. So in the inquiry toward the essence of truth, one needs to go deeper than the scientific conception of truth that, while not being false, is still superficial.

Comment: 2) As for where the accordance comes from, it is now a whole other question. Heidegger calls it *liberty* or sometime *the open*, but this won't help you much. To go further, I'd advise you to read the short text from Heidegger that the excerpt are from : [On the Essence of Truth](https://aphelis.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Martin-Heidegger-On-the-Essence-of-Truth.pdf). But ultimately, you should also be aware that Heidegger's goal is sometime more to lead to new questions than to new answers.

Answer (score -2):

The ground of being is not new but very old. All the famous ancient philosopherrs treated it from Thales to Aristotle. Generally this called metaphysics or ontology.

Technology is underappreciated in historical terms. It's one of the root causes of the Two World Wars. We might call it one of the material causes whilst the typical cause given by historians is an efficient or final cause. It's was also a material cause of Marxism as they considered its fruition would allow mankind to emancipate itself from labour.

Comment: We can say that technology played a role in both world wars, but saying technology was a "cause" of these wars seems unwarranted to me.

Comment: @Frank Would you accept the argument that the technical capacities to execute the Blitzkrieg was part of the decision making process of Nazi Germany to invade Poland, and that without the technical artifacts of the Wehrmacht and Luftwaffe, Hitler may not have launched the invasion? In fact, arguably, every dictator whose ambitions aren't constrained by temperament are constrained by the means they have to wage war?

Comment: In fact, wouldn't Bertrand Russell and Albert Einstein disagree with you since they signed and promoted the [Russell-Einstein Manifesto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%E2%80%93Einstein_Manifesto) calling for sober reflection on the damage nuclear technology implied in modern warfare?

Comment: The assertion "It's one of the root causes of the Two World Wars" seems to make the argument that "technology directly caused the two world wars" when it seems it was more of an enabler than a direct "cause" to me. As for nuclear technology and that manifesto, they date back to 1955. The 2 authors don't say that "nuclear technology caused the two wars".

Comment: @Frank: Thats why I said it was *one* of the *material* causes ... I didn't say it was the direct cause.